# allow logged user to enable cups printer using cupsenabler

Tags: fedora, cups

using fedora 20 it happens sometimes that printer goes on hold.

The only way of resuming is from root account (or eg localhost:631 after providing root credentials).

I was trying to alter /etc/cups/cupsd.conf without any success. What I expect is that it should be enough to have `@OWNER` in the following section of `<Policy authenticated>`

```
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer ...> 
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
```

but unfortunately it does not work (after `sysctl restart cups.service`) ...

I haven't seen any reasonable message in journal nor in /var/log/cups/error_log even after turning on debug

the only message is

```
E [04/Feb/2015:19:51:53 +0100] [Client 16] Returning HTTP Forbidden for Resume-Printer (ipp://localhost/printers/HP-P-1102w-wireless) from localhost
```